# Mouse works but Touch doesnot work in QML

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, qml, touchscreen, adafruit

I am working on a project which is based on RPI and Touchscreen and using QML/Qt Quick at the front end. For the touchscreen I am using **Adafruit 5 inch touchscreen** which takes touch responses with the microUSB. The touch on the RPI desktop works fine, but when I run the QML application and try to touch the button, it doesn't respond. The touch responds when there is a mouse pointer on the button. Also, I tried rotating the screen with:

```
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_ROTATION=180
```

but didn't work.

I don't know what wrong I am doing? Is there anyone who can help me with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Below are the parameters I am setting to run the application.

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/qt5pi/lib
export QML_IMPORT_PATH=/usr/local/qt5pi/qml
export QML2_IMPORT_PATH=/usr/local/qt5pi/qml
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=eglfs
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_TSLIB=1
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_HIDECURSOR=1
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_MOUSE_PARAMETERS=abs
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_WIDTH=210
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_HEIGHT=150

/usr/local/qt5pi/bin/qmlscene testQml.qml
```

The Test code testQml.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    id:rootTangle
    width:360
    height: 360
    color:"red"

    Rectangle {
        id: blueRec
        color: "blue"
        width: rootTangle.width/2
        height: rootTangle.height/6
        anchors.centerIn: rootTangle
        border.width:7
        border.color: "#000000"
        radius: 20
    }

    MouseArea {
        id:blueRecMouseArea
        anchors.fill:blueRec
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your system already supports the Touch screen input, and includes libinput or tslib. You can test if touch events arrive to evdev by using the `evtest` command, and touching your touch screen. You can also directly read from you touch screen driver with `cat /dev/input/eventX | hexdump`
2. If that works, that's probably an [input integration problem with Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html#input). Your options being libinput, or evdev directly. I recommand you to check you `configure` log then to understand if some module was not built due to a failed dependancy check. Quote from the same page:

> After running configure, make sure to inspect the output of it. Not
>   having the necessary eglfs backend, libudev, or libinput enabled due
>   to the corresponding configure tests failing are fairly common issues
>   that can be easily and quickly recognized this way. When there is an
>   undesired "no" result, run configure with -v to turn on verbose output
>   in order to see the compiler and linker invocations for each configure
>   test.

Comment: I check the configure output and I have all the necessary files for touch, for eg: eglfs.. Still getting this error.

Comment: Ok, do you know what's the path to your touch device ? If yes, does it output something when you play with it ? Or is it handled as standard mouse, and not a touch screen ?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the built-in input handler
`export QT_QPA_EGLFS_DISABLE_INPUT=1`

QT uses libinput as the default input-handler. If instead you want to use another handler, libinput should be disabled. Repercussions would be depending on what you choose to replace libinput with. In the case of tslib, it only supports single-touch. You can read more about it [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html)

Comment: Are there any possible repercussions from this?  Why do you think it will resolve the issue?

Comment: QT uses libinput as the default input-handler. If instead you want to use another handler, libinput should be disabled. Repercussions would be depending on what you choose to replace libinput with. In the case of tslib, it only supports single-touch. You can read more about it [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html)

Comment: Good information, you should include it in the actual answer, you'll probably get a few upvotes if you did